# Riemann Zeta Function and Including Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I'm a high-school senior attempting to make sense of the zeta function. I know Riemann regularized it to include complex numbers. Apparently, from this we could obtain that the sum of natural numbers may be assigned the value '-1/12' (zeta of -1)

What I don't get is how did extending the domain to complex numbers help in getting this result.

Thanks,

Comment: [A little bit of fun, related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555024/how-to-put-9-pigs-into-4-pens-so-that-there-are-an-odd-number-of-pigs-in-each-pe/555321#555321)

"the infinite summation is only valid for $s\gt 1$" - Where here we have $s=-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ is valid only for $\Re(s)>1$. It simply does not converge otherwise. By analytically continuing the Riemann zeta function we obtain a function which agrees with $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>1$, and which is also defined for all $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$. To answer your question, $-1$ is the complex number $-1+0i$. The analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function is defined at $-1+0i$ and it evaluates to $-1/12$.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now.

Comment: See also this question which shows an analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function to $\Re (s)>0$... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256992/derivative-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-for-res0... an improvement on $\Re(s)>1$, but still not the whole story !