# Derivative of the Riemann zeta function for any $s$

Tags: derivatives, riemann-zeta

There are a few questions on here asking for the derivative of the zeta function for $\Re(s)>0$, but is there a derivative for any $s$? What is it?

See here:

[Derivative of the Riemann zeta function for $Re(s)>0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256992/derivative-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-for-res0)

Comment: Yes, apart from the pole at $s=1$, $\zeta$ is a holomorphic complex function.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thanks! what is it?

Comment: It's $\zeta'(s)\ \ddot\smile$